# Which is the best way to test a background URLSession?

Tags: ios, swift3, background-process, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I'm following a sample code to download several images and show them in cells. For that, I configured an `URLSession` like this:

```
let backgroundConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "com.myexample.images")
self.backgroundSession = URLSession(configuration: backgroundConfig, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
```

Then, I perform the download of an image like this:

```
func downloadImage(imageUrl url: URL, imageId: Int, completion: ImageResult?) -> URLSessionDownloadTask? {
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    let task = backgroundSession.downloadTask(with: request)

    // Code here to keep track of the completion handler for this task

    task.resume()
    return task
}
```

I also conform to `URLSessionDownloadDelegate` and implement its `didCompleteWithError`, `didFinishDownloadingTo` and `urlSessionDidFinishEvents` methods. For this last method, I have this implementation:

```
func urlSessionDidFinishEvents(forBackgroundURLSession session: URLSession) {
    if let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate, let completionHandler = appDelegate.backgroundSessionCompletionHandler {
        appDelegate.backgroundSessionCompletionHandler = nil
        completionHandler()
    }
}
```

And then in `AppDelegate`:

```
var backgroundSessionCompletionHandler: (() -> Void)?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession identifier: String, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    backgroundSessionCompletionHandler = completionHandler
}
```

I don't know if this is actually working. I run the app in a simulator, I go to phone's Home to put the app in background state and I'm not able to see if neither `urlSessionDidFinishEvents` nor app delegate's `handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession` methods are called. Maybe because the downloads are too fast to see this.

How could I properly test this in a simulator? Am I missing something?

Comment: I use background communications/downloads in most of my systems: I use liberal use of console debugging statements along with logging for actual handsets.  Old-school, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

call this method `downloadImage` on `BackgroundFetch` of Appdelegate

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Swift.Void)
```

and then in debug mode, run app on device, then lock your phone and then from `XCode - Debug Menu`, select `Simulate Background Fetch`

Comment: Thank you, but actually this way I'm not exactly testing what I want, right? In the example I followed for using the background URL session, the `Background fetch` capability is not enabled... maybe the example is wrong?

Comment: You can enable it for sanity test and then can remove that capability. It is just for confirmation whether the feature is working in background or not.